# Obtain openid by using WeixinJSBridge from wechat

Tags: openid, wechat, weixinjsbridge

I was wondering if any WeChat experts out there can tell me if there is a way to obtain the users open id by using WeixinJSBridge or some other way when they are viewing a URL inside of wechat?

Most of the resources I find out there is in Chinese and I can't use it.

Thanks

Comment: Since January 2015 WeChat (Weixin) has replaced WeixinJSBridge with new API, and do have English wiki website here: http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT